# Display duplicate records in data.frame and omit single ones

Tags: r, duplicates, dataframe

I have been struggling with how to select ONLY duplicated rows of data.frame in R.
 For Instance, my data.frame is:

```
age=18:29
height=c(76.1,77,78.1,78.2,78.8,79.7,79.9,81.1,81.2,81.8,82.8,83.5)
Names=c("John","John","John", "Harry", "Paul", "Paul", "Paul", "Khan", "Khan", "Khan", "Sam", "Joe")
village <- data.frame(Names, age, height)

 Names age height
 John  18   76.1
 John  19   77.0
 John  20   78.1
 Harry  21   78.2
 Paul  22   78.8
 Paul  23   79.7
 Paul  24   79.9
 Khan  25   81.1
 Khan  26   81.2
 Khan  27   81.8
 Sam  28   82.8
 Joe  29   83.5
```

I want to see the result as following:

```
Names age height
John  18   76.1
John  19   77.0
John  20   78.1
Paul  22   78.8
Paul  23   79.7
Paul  24   79.9
Khan  25   81.1
Khan  26   81.2
Khan  27   81.8
```

Thanks for your time...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A solution using `duplicated` twice:

```
village[duplicated(village$Names) | duplicated(village$Names, fromLast = TRUE), ]


   Names age height
1   John  18   76.1
2   John  19   77.0
3   John  20   78.1
5   Paul  22   78.8
6   Paul  23   79.7
7   Paul  24   79.9
8   Khan  25   81.1
9   Khan  26   81.2
10  Khan  27   81.8
```

An alternative solution with `by`:

```
village[unlist(by(seq(nrow(village)), village$Names, 
                  function(x) if(length(x)-1) x)), ]
```

Comment: @SvenHohenstein, rep on this answer has been jumping around a bit. Maybe the OP doesn't realize that only one answer can be accepted ;)

Answer (score 3):

I find @Sven's answer using duplicated the "tidiest", but you can also do this many other ways. Here are two more:

1. Use `table()` and subset by matching the names where the tabulation is > 1 with the names present in the first column:

   ```
   village[village$Names %in% names(which(table(village$Names) > 1)), ]
   ```
2. Use `ave()` to "tabulate" in a little different manner, but subset in the same way:

   ```
   village[with(village, ave(as.numeric(Names), Names, FUN = length) > 1), ]
   ```

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you can use grouping and summary in a dplyr pipeline.

It's more lines of code and maybe more costly in compute. But, the advantage is that you can find duplicate rows by a composite key of multiple columns, rather than only duplicates from within one column.

```
library(tidyverse)


a <- c(8, 18, 19, 19, 19, 20, 30, 32, 32)
b <- c(1950, 1965, 1981, 1971, 1981, 1999, 1969, 1994, 1999)
c <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)
df <- data.frame(a, b, c)    
df

# Description:df[,3] [9 × 3]
# a
# <dbl>
# b
# <dbl>
# c
# <dbl>
# 8 1950    1       
# 18    1965    2       
# 19    1981    3       
# 19    1971    4       
# 19    1981    5       
# 20    1999    6       
# 30    1969    7       
# 32    1994    8       
# 32    1999    9       
# 9 rows

df[duplicated(df$a) | duplicated(df$a, fromLast = T), ]

# Description:df[,3] [5 × 3]
#  
#  
# a
# <dbl>
# b
# <dbl>
# c
# <dbl>
# 3 19  1981    3   
# 4 19  1971    4   
# 5 19  1981    5   
# 8 32  1994    8   
# 9 32  1999    9   
# 5 rows

df[duplicated(df$a, df$b) | duplicated(df$a, df$b, fromLast = T), ]

# Description:df[,3] [5 × 3]
#  
#  
# a
# <dbl>
# b
# <dbl>
# c
# <dbl>
# 3 19  1981    3   
# 4 19  1971    4   
# 5 19  1981    5   
# 8 32  1994    8   
# 9 32  1999    9   
# 5 rows

df %>%
  group_by(a, b) %>%
  summarise(a = a, b = b, c = c, n = n()) %>%
  subset(n > 1) %>%
  select(a, b, c)
# 
# A tibble:2 x 3
# Groups:a, b [1]
# a
# <dbl>
# b
# <dbl>
# c
# <dbl>
# 19    1981    3       
# 19    1981    5       
# 2 rows


df[duplicated(df, incomparables = c(c)), ]
# Error: argument 'incomparables != FALSE' is not used (yet)
# This error occurs even with no libraries loaded.
```

I may be missing something in the way `duplicated()` is used in brackets, but I couldn't figure it out.

Also, dplyr returns a tibble, dropping the index, which may be a drawback for you.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a solution using nested sapply:

```
> village_dups = 
village[unique(unlist(which(sapply(sapply(village$Names,function(x) 
which(village$Names==x)),function(y) length(y)) > 1))),]
> village_dups
   Names age height
1   John  18   76.1
2   John  19   77.0
3   John  20   78.1
5   Paul  22   78.8
6   Paul  23   79.7
7   Paul  24   79.9
8   Khan  25   81.1
9   Khan  26   81.2
10  Khan  27   81.8
```